# system() function in g++

Tags: c++

Here my Source from the log remove cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> // system
#include "header.h"
#include "ConfigFile.h"

using namespace std;

int glogs(int answer)
{
    ConfigFile cf("config.txt");
    string lang;
    double dChannel, dCore;
    lang = (const string)cf.Value("Main_Setting", "LANG");
    dChannel = cf.Value("Main_Setting", "CHANNEL");
    dCore = cf.Value("Main_Setting", "CORES");
    system("clear");
    if(lang == "ENG") {
        cout << "Remove the all Server logs...\n";
        for(int i=1; i < dChannel+1; i++){
            for (int c=1; c < dCore+1; c++){
                system("cd /usr/home/game2/channel" + i + atoi("/core") + c + atoi("/ && rm -R syslog && rm -R syserr"));
            }
        }
        cout << "delete logs done return to main menu...\n";
        system("sleep 10");
        system("./start");
        return answer;
    }
    if(lang == "DE"){
        cout << "Loesche alle Server logs...\n";
        for(int i=1; i < dChannel+1; i++){
            for (int c=1; c < dCore+1; c++){
                system("cd /usr/home/game2/channel" + i + atoi("/core") + c + atoi("/ && rm -R syslog && rm -R syserr"));
            }
        }
        cout << "loeschen erfolgreich, rurueck zum Hauptmenue...\n";
        system("sleep 10");
        system("./start");
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The line gives no waring or a error but he dont work

```
system("cd /usr/home/game2/channel" + i + atoi("/core") + c + atoi("/ && rm -R syslog && rm -R syserr"));
```

i have searched on stack for any hous but i have dont find a solutions for my proplem.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `atoi("/core")`?

Comment: you can't concatenate `char const *` using `+`.

Comment: the full patch is cd /usr/home/game2/channel1/core1/

Comment: Further, expressions like `"cd /usr/home/game2/channel" + i`, where `i` is `int`, are  *not* doing what you seem to think. In C, that's pointer arithmetic. I don't know what language you're coming from, or what language this is ported from, but that isn't how string-building in C works. It takes more than that, and is worthy of its own time in googlefu.

Comment: @KoriNatur Use a `std::ostringstream` to build the command to pass into the `system()` function.

Comment: The whole `system()` call is nonsensical as it is. What do you intend to achieve by attempting to convert strings that definitely aren't numerical to integers in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
system("cd /usr/home/game2/channel" + i + atoi("/core") + c + atoi("/ && rm -R syslog && rm -R syserr"));
```

should be like this

```
const auto path = "/usr/home/game2/channel" + std::to_string(i) + "/core" + std::to_string(c);
const auto cmd1 = "rm -R " + path + "/syslog";
const auto cmd2 = "rm -R " + path + "/syserr";

system(cmd1.c_str());
system(cmd2.c_str());
```

c++11 is needed to compile this and I did not test the code. I suggest not to use `system`, but `unlink` and `rmdir` or a c++ library that offers classes and functions for removing folders recursively.